# Regular expression: remove the (* and *)-delimited comment and extract first and last words

Tags: perl

I am facing an Issue while using regular expression,
Eg: I have something like this:

```
Wynk (* it is a Music online music player ; We can listen a song online and offline *) PAID;
youtube (* it is video player ; we can see the video online and we can download it *) free;
```

In above mentioned example I need to remove the `(*` and `*)`-delimited comment and extract the data "Wynk" and "PAID" from the first line and  "youtube" and "free" from the second.

I have done something like this

```
($first_word) =$_ =~ /^\s*(\w+)/; ($last_word) = $_ =~ /(\w+)\s*\;$/;
```

But I am not able to get perfect result for all data which looks similar to above mentioned example.

Comment: Can you show us a case that is not a "perfect result"? We can't help you correct your code if you only show us the part that works.

Comment: Is there any more accurate way to match first word and last word as i shown in my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two regexes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (<DATA>) {
  # skip empty lines
  next unless /\S/;

  my ($first, $last) = /\b(\w+)\b.*\b(\w+)\b\s*;/;

  say "$first / $last";
}

__DATA__
Wynk (* it is a Music online music player ; We can listen a song online and offline *) PAID;

youtube (* it is video player ; we can see the video online and we can download it *) free;
```

Output:

```
Wynk / PAID
youtube / free
```

But I think this isn't very different from what you already had. So I suspect you probably need to give us more details about what a "perfect result" is.

Comment: in this case `\b` assertions are useless because \w+ can't match non word character and can't backtrack

Comment: Actually, in this case, one of the `\b` assertions is essential. Can you tell which one it is? :-)

Comment: indeed the one after `.*`

Comment: Ya thanks man now it is working fine, after adding boundary condition to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   s/;\s*\z//;
   my ($id, $status) = /^ (.*) \(\* .* \)\* (.*)/sx
      or die;

   s/^\s+//, s/\s+\z// for $id, $status;

   ...
}
```

This solution works for ids like `Yahoo!` and `Joe's Streaming Service`.